# Trigger command on windows from another device (over the web)

Tags: remote-access, remote

I want to be able to turn on/off my Windows 10 hotspot remotely. Ideally, by logging onto my personal website, and toggling an on/off button. Is there any way that I can: 1) trigger the batch file with the command on my computer, by sending it a command from a different device over the web. 2) get the status of my hotspot, if it's on or off, (my initial guess is that it reports to my server every time it changes, and not that the server pings it for it's status)..

What are some ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the Hotspot ON and OFF via Command Line.

> **Turn on command** - netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow
>
> **Turn off command** - netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow

[Turn Hotspot ON and OFF](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-mobile-hotspot-from/93fe3f32-657f-4eee-a449-365447c22685?auth=1)

Then you can log onto the machine to manage the hotspot, or, if you can send Remote Commands, use PSEXEC to send the ON / OFF  commands to the workstation. PSEXEC is a SysInternals app.

There is not a status command (although you can ping it) so just turn it OFF or ON as needed.

[PSEXEC Commmand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "over the web" and "personal website," I am going on the assumption you are running a webserver.  If not, then you should modify your question.

You didnt say which webserver you are running, not that it matters too much.  With an extremely small amount of code, you can execute commands locally on the host machine.  This can be done with most any scripting languages your webserver supports.

Here is a [guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) for PHP to execute shell commands on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I am using a VPS managed by a third party, (Hostinger, where I host my php powered website). I am wondering if there is any software that can do what my question asks